# Understanding Test Output Calculation in DropConnect

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, dropout

I've been studying the DropConnect regularization technique for neural networks and I'm trying to understand how the test output is calculated. I understand that during training, DropConnect randomly sets a subset of weights to zero. However, I'm unclear on how this translates to the test phase.

Could someone please explain the process of calculating the test output in DropConnect? I would appreciate if you could provide a detailed explanation and, if possible, refer to any relevant sources or literature for further reading.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the paper or resource you're referring to? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.